# Doctrine Arraycollection not found @external host but working on local XAMPP

Tags: php, doctrine, xampp, web-hosting, arraycollection

Iam new with php and creating an rest API for test purposals (for an android app).
I use doctrine as ORM for my PHP project and it works fine localy with XAMPP.

Since i uploaded the project to an external hosting provider i got constantly an error:

```
[18-Feb-2016 10:25:12 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' not found in /home/aaapi/public_html/src/Alert.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 /home/aaapi/public_html/dataManagers/AlertManager.php(60): DemoApi\src\Alert->__construct('heerlen', Object(DemoApi\src\Child))
#1 /home/aaapi/public_html/create_alert.php(22): DemoApi\dataManagers\AlertManager->createAlert('heerlen', Array)
#2 {main}
thrown in /home/aaapi/public_html/src/Alert.php on line 40
```

I EXACLY followed http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html 5.5. (one to many bi directional)

I tried to remove

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

and replace the:

```
$this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    //replaced by
$this->children = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

This also doesn't fix the problem.

Has someone a solution?

Comment: Are the PHP versions equivalent?

Comment: just an stupid question: did you cleared `Symfony`'s cache?

Comment: it isn't a stupid question. I never heared about this. I googled it and i can clear it by a console command? but in which console? from my host? when yes then i need to mail my host to ask where to find this? or are iám totaly wrong? When i don't use the doctrine arraycollection everything works fine online to.

Comment: You should ssh to your host and, from the symfony folder, run `app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup`. If you cannot `ssh`, then, remove the `~/app/cache/*` folder

Comment: symfony is a framework? i don't use a framework, only doctrine nothing else. I cant find a "cache" dir in my whole FTP  directory structure. i also can't ssh becouse it is a "normal" webhosting package i hire from neostrada.nl

Comment: Ok, excuseme, I didn't nptice you were'nt using Symfony... I have got no experience using Doctrine by itself... I wish you have luck in finding a solution!

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help anyway!